Modifying System Files in AWS Workspaces Red Hat 8 Gold Image
I am attempting to make a gold image for AWS Workspaces Red Hat 8. There are three files that I modify before capturing the image: /etc/sudoers, /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and /etc/security/access.conf. I modify these files by utilizing sed for all of them, but specifically:
The sudoers file I use sudo tee -a to add lines at the bottom
I utilize sudo sed -i for modifying the others.
Now, the issue I am facing is that except for the sudoers file, the other two files I modify always reset when capturing and imaging the machine. By default, they don't include other folders either (not sure if that's even possible with access.conf), E.g. sshd_config comments out the "includedir /etc/sshd/sshd_config.d" line, so anything put into that folder doesn't count either way.
I have attempted to make these modifications After the image as well, by utilizing Crontab and a @reboot command. That way the image is captured, and it runs these commands After the new Workspace is provisioned. This failed unfortunately as well.
Does anyone happen to have an idea on making these changes appropriately and getting them to stick?
